# What is the meaning of XMLNS URL in xml document

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

i want to know, is there any real meaning of xmlns urls in xml document ?

i had refer to [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) . now when i change the `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`
to something else, it stopped working. w3c says namespace names(OR URL) is just for to distinguish xml tags. than why it is not working after changing url.

so i thought, may be it has something to do with that URL, so tried localy (without internet).. see following example..

XML Document. (first.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="first.xsl"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
     <cd>
        <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
        <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>DECCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1991</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The dock of the bay</title>
        <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSLT Document (first.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

so, its working fine localy. but if i change `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` to something else like `xmlns:xsl="http://www.abc.com"` it gives me error in the browser.

```
Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.
```

so, the only question is, is there any real meaning of this URLS in xmlns. if yes it has than why it did worked without internet and not by changing the url in xsl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any real meaning of this URLS in xmlns

**This is a fundamental XML question -- not an XSLT one.**

A namespace-uri serves the purpose of identifying a specific XML-based language -- by having all of the element names of this labguage in the same namespace (making all of them have that same namespace-uri).

Other than that, a namespace uri has no additional purpose.

Therefore, all XSLT elements (and some attributes) are in the `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` namespace and any element with name that hasn't this namespace-uri is *not* an XSLT element.

Here are more examples:

- XML Schema: `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
- SVG: `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`
- XSL-FO: `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format`
- XHTML: `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`
- XPath 2.0 and XQuery functions: `http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions`
- XLink: `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`
- MathML: `"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"`

Therefore, by modifying the XSLT namespace-uri in your stylesheet to something else, you are effectively saying: The names prefixed by the associated prefix (in your case "xsl") belong to the `"http://www.abc.com"` namespace, not to the XSLT namespace -- therefore they are not XSLT elements.

Then of course, when an XSLT processor sees that it has been fed with elements that are not XSLT elements, the XSLT processor complains about this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the namespaces that you have mentioned, are like java namespaces ? and those name spaces are already available with the browser right ?

Comment: @Hardik: There is some similarity with other languages' namespaces, however XML namespaces *aren't* hierarchical -- they are just a flat set of strings. As for "availability of namespaces in the browser", we usually call this *browser support* for one or another language. For example, browsers implementing HTML5 support SVG and MathML and allow XSLT to be executed on an XML file/document if the XML document starts with a specific PI (processing instruction).

Answer (score 10):

It's not a URL, it's a URI. That is, it's an identifier (a name), not a location (an address).

A namespace in XML is like a package name in Java; different vocabularies are defined in different namespaces to prevent conflicts and to claim ownership of the definition of the vocabulary. Like package names, the namespace becomes an implicit part of the names of elements in that namespace, so that `<para>` in the Docbook namespace has no connection with `<para>` in the DITA namespace.

James Clark wrote a good tutorial on namespaces here: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm

Comment: is this url ever accessed somehow (e.g. by xml xsd validation) i guess not right?

Comment: As I said, it's not a URL, it's a URI. An identifier, not an address. It is never dereferenced to fetch a resource from the web.

Comment: thx. i thought so but just wanted to make that clear, as it is blocked by my companies firewall and i was arguing against it

Answer (score 0):

Well the browser (respectively any XSLT processor) supports the XSLT language with XSLT elements in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`. If you use `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="first.xsl"?>` to link to an XML document which is not an XSLT stylesheet then of course the browser (respectively the XSLT processor) does not understand the code. In the XML world the qualified name of an item consists of a namespace and a local name and any tool only supports known names. If you serve XHTML as XML to a browser then you need to ensure that you use the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` for the XHTML elements, otherwise the browser won't recognize your elements, even if they happen to have the same local names as XHTML elements. The same happens with XSLT code, for the browser to recognize elements as XSLT elements, you need both the right namespace and the right local name.